# fmi -Ignoring unknown resource URI

Tags: openmodelica, fmi, jmodelica

I exported a model fmu from openmodelica OMEditor and it was FMU version 2.0 and I specified it as co-simulation. I am getting the following error:

fmistatus = OK; Test CS model Instance (logStatusWarning ): fmi2Instantiate: Ignoring unknown resource URI: (null)
fmi2Instantiate: Ignoring unknown resource URI: (null)
assert            | debug   | Failed to open file (null)/test_info.json for reading: No such file or directory
getBestJumpBuffer got mmc_jumper=0000000000000000, globalJumpBuffer=0000000000000000

I don't understand why it is unable to find the resource folder URI. It was working well for Model Exchange. I referred to the link below  and changed my path to extracted folder too but getting the same error.

https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/2623

Please suggest a way to get past this error.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this error during the export or import?

Comment: Hi this is during the import

Comment: Did you use OpenModelica for import. Its weird since OM doesn't have any import support for CS-FMU 2.0.

Comment: Have you tested the import in other tools (e.g., fmpy) and have you run the FMU Compliance Checker on it?